# Rails simple_form - Align radio buttons vertically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @comment do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :comment, label: 'Phrase you would like to add:' %>
    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Positive'] ,[false, 'Negative']], :first, :last, label: 'Emotion' %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine, but the radio buttons in `collection_radio_buttons` are side by side. How can I stack the radio buttons vertically on top of each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember running into the same issue. There probably is a better way to work around it but this worked for me:

```
<%= f.input :options, collection: [[true, 'Positive'], [false, 'Negative']], as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Emotion', label_method: :last } %>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

There are two other options you can use.

**Option 1:**

Assign a css class to each item in the collection and apply styling accordingly.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Positive'] ,[false, 'Negative']], :first, :last, label: 'Emotion', item_wrapper_class: :block_radio_button_collection %>
```

This wraps each item in the collection, i.e. each pair of label and radio button with the default wrapper tag and sets `class="block_radio_button_collection"` on them.

Then you'd need to add the style definition for the css class `block_radio_button_collection` in your css file.

```
.block_radio_button_collection {
  display: block;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Wrap each item in the collection with a block element e.g. `div`:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Positive'] ,[false, 'Negative']], :first, :last, label: 'Emotion', item_wrapper_tag: :div %>
```

This changes the wrapper of each item in the collection i.e. each pair of label and radio button to `div`.